# Estimates for Stirling's formula remainder

Tags: calculus, approximation

It is proved in [*Advanced Calculus*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471025666) by Angus Taylor, § 20.8, that

$$\log n!=\log \left( \left( \frac{n}{e}\right) ^{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\right)
+r_{n},$$

where

$$r_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }S_{k}$$

with

$$S_{k}=\sum_{p=n+1}^{\infty }\frac{k}{2(k+1)(k+2)p^{k+1}}.$$

This formula for $r_{n}$ provides a method for finding the estimate

$$\frac{1}{12\left( n+1\right) }<r_{n}<\frac{1}{12\left( n-1\right) }.$$

Indeed

$$\frac{1}{k\left( n+1\right) ^{k}}=\sum_{p=n+1}^{\infty }\int_{p}^{p+1}\frac{%
1}{x^{k+1}}\mathrm dx<\sum_{p=n+1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}$$

$$\sum_{p=n+1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}<\sum_{p=n+1}^{\infty }\int_{p-1}^{p}%
\frac{1}{x^{k+1}}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{kn^{k}},$$

and so

$$\frac{1}{2(k+1)(k+2)\left( n+1\right) ^{k}}<S_{k}<\frac{1}{2(k+1)(k+2)n^{k}}
$$

$$\frac{1}{12\left( n+1\right) }<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{%
2(k+1)(k+2)\left( n+1\right) ^{k}}<r_{n}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{%
2(k+1)(k+2)n^{k}}<\frac{1}{12\left( n-1\right) }.$$

---

**Added**:The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) pointed to in the comment gives an approximation based on the Euler-MacLaurin formula in terms of the Bernoulli numbers and states that it can also be obtained by repeated integration by parts. The Stirling series that appears in the same article is different from the one above.

---

**Question** (edited): Are there better estimates of $r_{n}$ based on different methods?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates

Comment: @Hans Lundmark, Thanks. Now I am more pessimist of getting better answers than the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: I recall reading a paper that used both the trapezoidal rule and the midpoint rule to generate Stirling's formula with remainder; however, since the truncation error of those two quadrature methods is in fact the Euler-Maclaurin formula in a different garb, that approach might as well be duplicating that which is already in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a paper [Stirling's Series Made Easy](http://biblio.ugent.be/input/download?func=downloadFile&fileOId=451038) by Chris Impens that states in Corollary 3

$$ \frac{1}{12n} - \frac{1}{360n^3} < r_n < \frac{1}{12n}$$

and (the interesting part) that the constant $1/360$ cannot be improved. I confess to not having
read the paper closely.

Answer (score 1):

T. H. Grönwall [proved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1967180) in $1918$ that
$$
\frac{1}{{12(n + h)}} < r_n  < \frac{1}{{12n}},
$$
for any $n\ge 1$, with
$$
h = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\mathop {\max }\limits_{x > 0} \frac{{\log (1 + x^2 )}}{x} = 0.12807872 \ldots \,.
$$
More generally, he proved that
$$
r_n  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{2k(2k - 1)n^{2k - 1} }}}  + \frac{{B_{2N} }}{{2N(2N - 1)(n + \theta_{n,N} )^{2N - 1} }}
$$
for any $n,N\ge 1$, with a suitable $0<\theta_{n,N}<h$. Here the $B_k$ denote the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).